# HTTP status code for sending back just the meta-data not full data

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I am looking for an appropriate HTTP status code that tells the receiver that just the meta-data is being sent, not the complete data.

For example, say you do an HTTP GET:

```
GET /foo?meta_data_only=yes
```

the server won't look up the complete data, just send some metadata back about the endpoint, for example. Is there an HTTP status code for the response that can represent this? I would guess it's in the 200s or 300s somewhere?

Comment: Are you returning the metadata as headers or in the body? If it were headers, I’d say 204 No Content.

Comment: Yeah meta-data in the headers, most likely empty body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your metadata is being returned in the headers, I would send a status code of 204 No Content.

https://httpstatuses.com/204

> The server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no
> additional content to send in the response payload body.
>
> **Metadata** in
> the response header fields refer to the target resource and its
> selected representation after the requested action was applied.

This sounds exactly like what you’re looking for: a successful response that contains no body, and metadata in the headers that provide additional about the resource.

Another thing worth noting is that it’s common practice to use the HTTP verb `HEAD` when you only want metadata. `HEAD` is very similar to `GET`, except that it specifies that you do not want a body back. For example if you do a HEAD to an image url, you will get a 204 No Content response and some metadata about the file such as Content-Type, Content-Size, maybe ETag, but you won’t be sent all of the file data. A lot of web servers (such as Nginx) support this behavior out of the box for static files. I would recommend that you stop using your querystring parameter, and instead implement HEAD versions of your endpoints. That would make the intention even more clear and intuitive.

Comment: Good thinking, if nobody has a better suggestion will accept soon thanks

Comment: I just updated my example with another suggestion for you. @AlexanderMills

Comment: No problem! In the past I’ve seen a HEAD request used on a paginated JSON API endpoint that typically returns a collection of results. The HEAD version has no body, but had headers returned that give details about the current per page value, how many pages of results there are, how many total results there are, etc. Then the server sees this and chooses to only do count queries, since that’s all that’s needed to fulfill the request (as opposed to selecting a ton of records for nothing).

Comment: I suppose supporting both HEAD and a magic query parameter name wouldn't be the end of the world..but yeah using HEAD and 204 response is good.

Comment: You could definitely do both if you see value in both. I personally would only do the HEAD one, but that’s just me. As long as you clearly document how things work for whoever is using it, do what you want!

Comment: Oh, and if you’re using a web framework for your API, be sure to read the documentation regarding HEAD requests. Some of them have some out of the box support there or at least some preset conventions for how to build handlers for a HEAD request in the API. It may save you some work.